# Maintain multiple migration files in parallel in dropwizard

Tags: hibernate, migration, liquibase, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard 0.8.1 application which uses multiple (two) hibernate-powered databases. However, i would like to keep the migration-bundles for both databases separate from each other.

How to do that? For the hibernate bundles, i can set the name(), so that metrics wont be registered twice with the same name, but it seems like its not possible to set the file name for the migrations...

Answer (score 1):

This functionality has been added in DW 1.0.0.
Its not currently released so you can probably work with the snapshot.

From github currently [Migrations.rst](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/docs/source/manual/migrations.rst)

Copying the relevant portion here:

**Support For Adding Multiple Migration Bundles**

Assuming migrations need to be done for two different databases, you would need to have two different data source factories:

```
public class ExampleConfiguration extends Configuration {
@Valid
@NotNull
private DataSourceFactory database1 = new DataSourceFactory();

@Valid
@NotNull
private DataSourceFactory database2 = new DataSourceFactory();

@JsonProperty("database1")
public DataSourceFactory getDb1DataSourceFactory() {
    return database1;
}

@JsonProperty("database2")
public DataSourceFactory getDb2DataSourceFactory() {
    return database2;
}
}
```

Now multiple migration bundles can be added with unique names like so:

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<ExampleConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new MigrationsBundle<ExampleConfiguration>() {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDb1DataSourceFactory();
        }

        @Override
        public String name() {
            return "db1";
        }
    });

    bootstrap.addBundle(new MigrationsBundle<ExampleConfiguration>() {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDb2DataSourceFactory();
        }

        @Override
        public String name() {
            return "db2";
        }
    });
}
```

To migrate your schema:

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db1 migrate helloworld.yml
```

and

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db2 migrate helloworld.yml
```

Note

Whenever a name is added to a migration bundle, it becomes the command that needs to be run at the command line. eg: To check the state of your database, use the status command:

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db1 status helloworld.yml
```

or

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db2 status helloworld.yml
```

By default the migration bundle uses the "db" command. By overriding you can customize it to provide any name you want and have multiple migration bundles. Wherever the "db" command was being used, this custom name can be used.

There will also be a need to provide different change log migration files as well. This can be done as

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db1 migrate helloworld.yml --migrations <path_to_db1_migrations.xml>
java -jar hello-world.jar db2 migrate helloworld.yml --migrations <path_to_db2_migrations.xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

*In addition to [@SouravMitra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35227865/2012372) on how to define multiple migration bundles with Dropwizard 1.0.0 and up:*

If you want to maintain multiple database migration changelogs as **separate files**, yet still packaged in your application jar without having to reference them using the `--migrations <external-file-path-to-migrations.xml>` command line parameter, you can configure the changelog filename as part of the migration bundle by overriding `getMigrationsFileName()` as follows:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<ExampleConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new MigrationsBundle<ExampleConfiguration>() {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDb1DataSourceFactory();
        }

        @Override
        public String name() {
            return "db1";
        }

        @Override
        public String getMigrationsFileName() {
            return "migrations_db1.xml";
        }
    });

    bootstrap.addBundle(new MigrationsBundle<ExampleConfiguration>() {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDb2DataSourceFactory();
        }

        @Override
        public String name() {
            return "db2";
        }

        @Override
        public String getMigrationsFileName() {
            return "migrations_db2.xml";
        }
    });
```

The following commands would then automatically use the respective `migrations_db1.xml` and `migrations_db2.xml` migrations files from `src/main/resources` packaged within your application jar to migrate the separate databases:

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db1 migrate helloworld.yml
```

and

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db2 migrate helloworld.yml
```