# Multiple databases in dropwizard

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, dropwizard

I am trying to read and write into two databases and I am running into issues:

config.yml

```
database1:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: user1
  password: user!23
  url: jdbc:mysql://url.to.connect:3306/db1
  properties: charSet: UTF-8
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s
  minSize: 8
  maxSize: 32
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
  checkConnectionHealthWhenIdleFor: 10s
  closeConnectionIfIdleFor: 1 minute

database2:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: user2
  password: user!23
  url: jdbc:mysql://url.to.connect:3306/db2
  properties: charSet: UTF-8
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s
  minSize: 8
  maxSize: 32
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
  checkConnectionHealthWhenIdleFor: 10s
  closeConnectionIfIdleFor: 1 minute
```

configuration.java

```
public class ExampleConfiguration extends Configuration {
@Valid
@NotNull
private DataSourceFactory database1 = new DataSourceFactory();

@Valid
@NotNull
private DataSourceFactory database2 = new DataSourceFactory();

@JsonProperty("database1")
public DataSourceFactory getDb1DataSourceFactory() {
    return database1;
}

@JsonProperty("database2")
public DataSourceFactory getDb2DataSourceFactory() {
    return database2;
}
}
```

Now following: [Maintain multiple migration files in parallel in dropwizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913963/maintain-multiple-migration-files-in-parallel-in-dropwizard), I tried to add a bootstrap bundle as follows:

```
@Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap< ExampleConfiguration > bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addCommand(new RenderCommand());
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle());
    bootstrap.addBundle(new MigrationsBundle<ExampleConfiguration>() {
      @Override
      public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
        return configuration.getDb1DataSourceFactory();
      }
    });

    bootstrap.addBundle(new MigrationsBundle<ExampleConfiguration>() {
      @Override
      public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
        return configuration.getDb2DataSourceFactory();
      }
    });
    bootstrap.addBundle(hibernateBundle);

  }
```

But I got `command 'db' has been already used`. I am still unclear what is happening in `initialize()`. How can I switch between DB instances for read and write operations?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override each `MigrationsBundle` implementation's method `name` to provide unique command's name. Then using CLI you will need to specify correct name to use according database configuration.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by migrationBundle's implementation method?

Comment: `MigrationsBundle` is an abstract class, so you are actually implementing it each time when you add it to bootstrap. You should override method `name` and provide unique return value for it.

Comment: Thanks but how will DAO know which DB to write into? Shouldn't we need to create the dao for every single DB and use them to write in DB? [https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-jdbi]

Comment: Yes, you would need separate `Jdbi` instances for each data source and DAOs created by them.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the JDBI instances should be sufficient. Why do we need a separate `migrationBundle`?

Comment: If you need to run migrations on both DBs then you need two migration bundles.

Comment: Sorry but is it necessary to create the migrationsBundle? I do not actually know what it actually does. I assume it is for JDBC connection and access data from SQL data and use it. Hence, we create migrations bundle? Since, I need to read/write from db2 I need to create the `name` and bundle for that as well. In `run` I need to create the DAOs as well. Right?

Comment: `MigrationBundle` is needed only in case if your application is responsible for database migrations - all sorts of DDL: creating tables, columns, indexes, etc.

Comment: I am getting `java.util.Optional io.dropwizard.db.PooledDataSourceFactory.getValidationQuery()` I am not sure why I am getting that because I followed the steps on https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-jdbi